# Format to pass to mdp time picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

time-picker  i have to pass the time to picker but  it is not displaying in picker i am not getting to bind the time what i extracted from  date

```
$scope.eventStartTime = new moment($scope.editEvent.eventStartDate).format("hh:mm:ss A");
<mdp-time-picker data-ng-model="eventStartTime"></mdp-time-picker>
```

here

```
$scope.editEvent.eventStartDate = 01-24-2017 3:46 PM;
```

from above above code i am extrarting the time and getting the result as 3:46 PM but not able to bind to picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mdp-time-picker` expects model to be Date object. No need to use `moment.format`

You can use `mdp-format` to specify the format.

```
<mdp-time-picker mdp-format="hh:mm:ss A" ng-model="eventStartDate"></mdp-time-picker>
```

and, Use `moment()` constructor to create a date object

```
$scope.eventStartDate = moment('01-24-2017 3:50 PM', "MM-DD-yyyy hh:mm A").toDate();
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJoPPv)

Comment: i have value for eventStartDate is 01-24-2017 3:50 PM how to display only 3:50 PM in time picker

Comment: If i have two time pickers how to give min time and max time, Any help please